# Is it advisable to use ContentEditable for a web form?

Tags: html, contenteditable, inline-editing

I want to make a form type of editor that edits the text right on the page and commits changes on cursor-out of each field. There's no font or style alteration, just straight boxes.

I saw some things like [JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable) But the boxes and the need to press 'ok' to commit seems slightly unattractive and unintuitive.

I was wondering about just applying `contentEditable="true"` to each element.. I imagine that will achieve the same thing. Since it wouldn't be a form with inputs, though, I would have to submit changes via javascript, I'd imagine, but that's workable for my situation. (it also seems somewhat more straightforward than worrying about javascript for every element like with JEditable or something similar.

Is that a reasonable solution? I'm not worried about mobile browser support for this particular part of the site (hopefully iOS5 will support it though or something...).

Comment: ContentEditable will work fine, except that if it is not an input box, it won't be user input friendly. The best course of action is to have a textarea in a div that is floating and hidden, and then move it to the location of the edit, as the top element.
You would of course also need to copy the text from your current element to the textbox and then make it vanish and/or commit on enter or the like.

Comment: JEditable can be configured to not have buttons, but submit onblur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code wise it would need to look something like this:

> ```
> $(".YourElementClassHere").click(function () { 
>    $("#YourTextArea").position($(this).position());
>    $("#YourTextArea").css("display", "block");
> });
>
> $("#YourTextArea").click(function() {
>   if ( event.which == 13 ) {
>      $("#YourTextArea").css("display", "none");
>      // Do something to commit this: $("#YourTextArea").text();
>   }
> });
> ```

This is jQuery syntax btw, for anyone that shouldn't know this.
I hope this helps, seeing as I am a bit rusty, this javascript might need a bit of alteration.

Comment: I can work with that.  I'm wondering if there's any reasonable way to have the input take-over the styling of the text-box so that it looks seamless. I can grab specific styles like that with jQuery I'd imagine..

Comment: i'm not sure about what `( event.which == 13 )` is doing?

Comment: Yes it is possible, but stuff like textareas can be very complicated to work with at times, but you can do the exact same styling with javascript as you can with regular css.
event.which is a JQuery compilation of the different ways the different browsers detect keypresses rolled into one, key 13 is enter, you can look up other keys on the net.
Sorry for the very late reply.